# How to solve module not found error in Jupyter

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

1-I use Mac OS (Mac OS Catalina 10.15.5)

2-Downloaded Anaconda from its website

3-anaconda3

My code is:

```
import numpy as np

import pickle

import pandas as pd

filename="load.csv"
```

The Error I get is:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-0c11310eb0ac> in <module>
----> 1 import numpy as np
      2 import pickle
      3 import pandas as pd
      4 filename="load.csv"
 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Comment: Hey I think you don't have numpy installed in your environment. In a jupyter cell you can install numpy:.  `!pip install numpy`

Comment: make sure you are in the right kernel, in Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `numpy` and `pandas` packages before being able to import them. You don't need to do it for `pickle` because it's a native package (it is already installed in Python).

The way you do it is :

```
conda install numpy
conda install pandas
```

in your terminal.

Comment: It says all requested packages are already installed. But, when I try to check the version; I can't get the version

Comment: `It says all requested packages are already installed.` How did you check that ?

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal do:

```py
pip install numpy
pip install pandas
```

Comment: numpy=installed (1.17.2)

Comment: pip install pandas
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) (1.17.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.6.1 in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) (2019.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.6.1->pandas) (1.12.0)

Comment: pip install pickle
Collecting pickle
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pickle (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pickle

Comment: The problem is that pickle is a module in Python's standard library. There is no need to install it

Comment: #list the current work dir
os.getcwd()
#change the current work dir
os.chdir() change the path, and import module